# Why it is called Gross and Net

Tags: meaning-in-context

I can't find the right keywords to use in google search to find the reason behind on why the *whole profit* was called **Gross** and the *remaining profit* as **Net**.

I want to know the deeper meaning because I always forgot which is which.

Comment: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=gross&allowed_in_frame=0

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: [net (adj.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=net) *"remaining after deductions," 1510s, from earlier sense of "trim, elegant, clean, neat" (c. 1300), from Old French net "clean, pure," from Latin nitere "to shine, look bright, glitter" (see neat). Meaning influenced by Italian netto "remaining after deductions."*